# Conditional expectation of a linear combination of a discrete random variable and a parameter

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have seen this calculation in a paper, and I didn't understand the development:
$\mathbb{E}[y+X|X\leq M-y]\Pr[X\leq M-y]=\sum_{l=0}^{M-y}(y+l)\Pr(X=l)$.
$M$ and $y$ are two parameters and $X$ is a discrete random variable.
Please can you explain to me how this result is obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an event $A$ of non-zero probability, the conditional expectation of a nonnegative random variable $Z$ given the event $A$ is such that
$$
\mathbb E[Z\vert A]=\frac{\mathbb E[Z1_A]}{\mathbb P(A)}\cdot
$$

Applying the formula above with $Z=y+X$ and $A=\{X\le M-y\}$ yields (assuming that $X$ is valued in $\mathbb N$)
$$
\mathbb E[y+X\vert X\le M-y]\mathbb P(X\le M-y)=\mathbb E[(y+X)1_{\{X\le M-y\}}]=\sum_{l=0}^{M-y}(y+l)\mathbb P(X=l).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please can you tell me what this formula is called?

Comment: Which formula? The first is the formula for a conditional expectation given an event, the last one is sometimes referred to as the law of the unconscious statistician https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: What if X is a continuous random variable?